# `type` doesn't recognize the first argument (CPython)

Tags: python, virtual-machine, cpython

CPython doesn't recognize the following argument:

```
type.__subclasscheck__(object)
# gives us: TypeError: __subclasscheck__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

type.__subclasscheck__(object, object) # works fine
# give us: True
```

Why does it behave so?

PS: Using Python3 on Debian 10

Comment: The suggest duplicate is not directly related to my question!

Comment: I don't really get the question. __subclasscheck is usually implemented to check one object against another. Calling it with ine argument really makes no sense. This is what ´TypeError: __subclasscheck__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)´ tells you as well.

Comment: "__subclasscheck__() takes exactly one argument (0 given)". This doesn't make sense because I passed a argument. I am thinking now... Being type a metaclass. (a parent object, would like to mean), the method could work differently from the others. Anyway, the interpreter responses in a not correct way.

Comment: It works just like other methods. `type.__subclasscheck__` is an unbound method, so you either need to call it on an instance, like: `object.__classcheck__(...)` or pass `self` explicitly: `type.__subclasscheck__(object, ...)`.

Comment: object.__subclasscheck__(type). Try it. Perhaps will you get the point I'm trying to show you.

Comment: If I do `object.__subclasscheck__(type)` cython compiles fine

Comment: But type.__subclasscheck__(object) didn't. (python3). This is the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` is not a regular class. It is the [metaclass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/2907819) of all classes in python. That means that class methods like `mro()` or `__subclasscheck__()` are defined as regular methods on the `type` metaclass, and can be used as bound methods only on instances of that metaclass, i.e. all python classes except for `type` itself.

For example, let's experiment with the classes `int` and `object`.
First, let's make it clear that `type` is the metaclass of both classes:

```py
isinstance(object, type)  # True
isinstance(int, type)     # True
issubclass(object, type)  # False
issubclass(int, type)     # False
```

But, as `int` inherits from `object`, it is a subclass of `object`:

```
issubclass(int, object)  # True
```

Now, what is `__subclasscheck__()`?

```
type(type.__subclasscheck__)    # method_descriptor
type(object.__subclasscheck__)  # builtin_function_or_method
str(inspect.signature(type.__subclasscheck__))    # (self, subclass, /)
str(inspect.signature(object.__subclasscheck__))  # (subclass, /)
```

So, `__subclasscheck__()` is a method of `type`, which means when used as `type.__subclasscheck__` it will be unbound, and when used as `X.__subclasscheck__` it will be bound to the class X.

Knowing that, you could probably figure out the right way of using `__subclasscheck__()`:

```
# As an unbound method:
type.__subclasscheck__(object, int)  # True
# As a bound method:
object.__subclasscheck__(int)        # True
```

Note that both ways are logically equal.

It is also worth noting that if you actually want to check if a class is a subclass of another, you should just be using the builtin function `issubclass`.

Comment: This could be considered as a matter of scoping? if not only of method placement - it can be quite tricky to figure out? This clarification helped though. Departing  from the OP's example, when implementing a class as a subclass of `type` using a metaclass that's a sublass of `type`, it seems one may  need to implement `__subclasscheck__` and `__instancecheck__`, both at the instance scope in the metaclass and at the instance scope in the implementing type class - at least for checking whether a value is an instance of a class using second as a metaclass ... tricky! that was helpful though